# Why isn't eslint processing the converted code from webpack loader but scanning the source files?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I used create-react-app to create the project, then 'npm run eject' the project and added my custom webpack loader in webpack.config.js.

In myLoader.js, I have seen aaa converted to bbb, but eslint still reported an error 'aaa' is not defined  no-undef

```js
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                  options: { },
                },
                require.resolve('../myLoader')  // here is my loader
              ]
            },
```

```js
myLoader.js

module.exports = (src) => {
    const result = src.replace(/aaa/g, 'bbb')
    console.log(result)
    return result
}
```

```js
app.js

const bbb = 'content'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <div> {aaa}</div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint doesn't know you are doing a replacement in your webpack loaders so you might want to instruct the tool that `aaa` will eventually be defined.

You can do this by telling eslint `aaa` is a [global variable](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options#specifying-globals) either in the eslint configuration or as a comment in the files where you use `aaa`.

```
// .eslintrc.json
{
  "globals": {
    "aaa": "readable"
  }
}
```

```
// app.js
/* global aaa:readable */
```